# Unable to use mysql in the same plan which creates MySQL server

Tags: mysql, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create an AWS RDS instance and then want to manage db users with the terraform. So first, I have created a RDS instance and then initialised the mysql provider with the created RDS instance to use it further for user management. But mysql provider is taking default endpoint (127.0.0.1) to connect during planning phase. Following is my code

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
    name            = "${var.name}"
    master_username = "${var.master_username}"
    master_password = "${random_string.password.result}"
    .
    .
    .
}

provider "mysql" {
    endpoint = "${aws_rds_cluster.default.endpoint}"
    username = "${aws_rds_cluster.default.master_username}"
    password = "${random_string.password.result}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per terraform's current implementation, To initialize MySQL provider, MySQL has to exist first. That's why it's failing because during plan phase your RDS instance doesn't exist. There is already an open issue (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18720) for this on terraform GitHub repo.
So to manage it, you have to first create RDS instance and then you can use the credentials of that to initialize the mysql provider